# What's the most fun way to make a Santa Claus hat? 

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, shaders, particles, physics

I bought a 3D printer, and as my first project I decided to print a hat missing in my Santa Claus costume, however it came out pretty stiff and without any geonodes hair??? So I returned the 3D printer to the shop as defective and decided to use a normal printer instead, but then the hat came out rather flat…

I found the missing hat eventually but still can't get it out of my head…

#### How would YOU make a Santa Claus hat?

Of course without printing requirement, or any other, [you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/244655/60486) [know](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/100203/60486) [the](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/207755/60486) [drill](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/265731/60486).

[image]

Comment: Damn I missed these challenges. Nice one, and Christmas themed too!

Comment: felt, scissors, and tape?  Oops, that's a Twitter answer!

Comment: _"decided to use a normal printer instead, but then the hat came out rather flat"_ You could buy two more normal printers and tape the three hats together, thus effectively giving you a 3d-printer at the price of three normal printers!

Comment: I've been so swamped this Xmas.. sorry  to have missed this one...

Answer (score 12):

> I decided to print a hat missing in my Santa Claus costume, however it came out without any geonodes hair???

The problem is that you need support for your hair, because the people who make 3D printers are lazy.

[image]

After printing, carefully cut away the support struts with a sharp knife.

If you don't have a sharp knife around, you can just print one!

[image]

Don't forget to mark edges as sharp where appropriate.

> pretty stiff

3D printers don't support deformation yet.  What you need to do is print out a lot of hats and then change your hat 24 times a second.  It sounds tough, but like everything else, it gets easier with practice.

Comment: I think I need to print two knives, otherwise how do I cut the supports out of a knife? 

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Oh yeah, I didn't think it all the way through.  2 should be plenty though!  Blender keeps giving me console spam, but it previews good, so 

Comment: I've been told knaves always lie (on the print bed), that looks more like a knight.

Answer (score 12):

Possibly the most readable node tree...

[image]

[image]

---

Bonus: Santa Claus underpants

[image]

Comment: That is actually funny - being able to arrange and color your GN nodes to look like the object you are modeling. This could be a trend on its own.

Comment: @RumenBelev it is! [quellenform's tree](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/266334/60486), [my pentagram](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/284724/60486), [TensorAn's city](https://i.imgur.com/ZIyqqqh.png) (Discord)

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Extra bonus, behind the scenes:

[image]

Comment: I see you're a fan of [Peter Jackson](https://i.redd.it/nt034kj4yg521.gif)

Comment: Markus, Peter Jackson taught me everything.